# Link inside PHP script not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Using wordpress, trying to amend a notice which popsup, so changed the prior message to this

```
        Tribe__Notices::set_notice( 'events-not-found', sprintf( esc_html__( 'No current bookable %1$s listed under %2$s. Please <a href="the-link-to-a-page">click here</a> to enquire about future courses.', 'the-events-calendar' ), $events_label_plural, $tax_term, $events_label_plural ) );
```

How ever it's doesn't create the Click Here link and actually prints the code

```
Please <a href="the-link-to-a-page">click here</a>
```

the-link-to-page is just for demo, using the correct URL in code, what am I doing wrong

Comment: did you try to not call the esc_html__ function?

Comment: I worked it out in the end, I see I had to use a %3$s where the link should be the reference the $link = "http://www at the end of the code

Answer (score 2):

Well, `esc_html__` escapes HTML – so that is working as indeted. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I have read the link, but i'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to all this, any chance one of you clever chaps can re-write how the line should look correctly?